# Customize range seek bar

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am building an custom range seekbar for my app. I want to create the range seekbar same as image below:

[image: Custom Range Seekbar]

I researched and found the custom range seekbar at: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/.
But this seekbar only has two thumb for start point and end point. What I need is the new thumb between two thumbs to show progress of video.

I saw many apps use it but I don't know how to customize the range seekbar.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution for your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make new thumb by yourself. Draw it same as two thumb in range seekbar too. To show progress video, you need to update new thumb again when progress change.